# How to analyse the result of django debug toolbar?

Tags: django, web, django-templates, django-debug-toolbar

From the debug result, I can see my website browser timing is really long.
Basically I create 13000 items for the blog table. Seems like it takes not a long time to do sql query.

[The debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joLfq.png)

My questions is how can I identify bottlenecks from debug result. Why it loads so slowly, takes near 20s. How can I reduce the domContentLoadedEvent and domloading Time.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe  i should use pagination to avoid render all the objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct answer to your question using Debug Toolbar: enable the profiling panel.

Note: this will remove the other panels if you don't have the default panels in the dictionary, as in the example.

[Docs](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html)

`settings.py`

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = {
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
}
```